# My list won't show after replacing Listview with a Recycleview

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter, android-recyclerview

so I was trying to replace my listview with a recyclerview in order to improve my app,
now my activity doesnt show the list.
I was checking the adapter and I couldn't find any mistake

This was my **ListView Adapter:**

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private Context context;
private List<Salary> salaryList;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<Salary> salaryList) {
    this.salaryList = salaryList;
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_card, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.fieldName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fieldName);
        holder.txtSalary = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtSalary);
        holder.cardview = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardview);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    Salary salary = salaryList.get(position);
    holder.salary = salary;
    holder.cardview.setTag(salary);
    holder.fieldName.setText(salary.getField());
    holder.txtSalary.setText(salary.getSalary());

    holder.cardview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Salary salary = (Salary) v.getTag();
            Intent i = new Intent(context, ViewSalary.class);
            i.putExtra(ViewSalary.FIELD_NAME, salary.getField());
            i.putExtra(ViewSalary.SALARY_NUM, salary.getSalary())
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    });

public static class ViewHolder {
    Salary salary;
    TextView fieldName;
    TextView txtSalary;
    CardView cardview;
}
```

}

and now here is my new **RecyclerView Adapter**:

public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private List<Salary> salaryList;

public CustomAdapter(List<Salary> salaryList) {
    this.salaryList = new ArrayList<Salary>();
    this.salaryList.addAll(salaryList);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SalaryViewHolder salaryViewHolder, int i) {
    Salary salary = salaryList.get(i);
    salaryViewHolder.fieldName.setText(salary.getField());
    salaryViewHolder.txtSalary.setText(salary.getSalary());
    salaryViewHolder.salary = salary;
    salaryViewHolder.cardview.setTag(salary);

}


@Override
public SalaryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.
            from(viewGroup.getContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.item_card, viewGroup, false);

    return new SalaryViewHolder(itemView);
}



public class SalaryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    protected Salary salary;
    protected TextView fieldName;
    protected TextView txtSalary;
    protected CardView cardview;
    public SalaryViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        fieldName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fieldName);
        txtSalary = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtSalary);
        cardview = (CardView) view;
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Salary salary = (Salary) v.getTag();
                Intent i = new Intent(context, ViewSalary.class);
                i.putExtra(ViewSalary.FIELD_NAME, salary.getField());
                i.putExtra(ViewSalary.SALARY_NUM, salary.getSalary());;
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

any ideas??

Comment: Can you post your `Activity` code /

Comment: Did you use any `LayoutManager` like `LinearLayoutManager` and set that to your `RecycleriVew`

Comment: private List<Salary> feedList;
    private RecyclerView recycleView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter  listAdapter;

        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recycleView.setLayoutManager(llm);
        recycleView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        listAdapter = new CustomAdapter(feedList);
        recycleView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

Comment: From your code i assume that the feedList is empty so you don't see any data.

Comment: I populate my feedList with this:
                  for (ParseObject salaryObject : parseObjects) {
                    Salary salary = Salary.ParseToSalary(salaryObject);
                    feedList.add(salary);

                }

I have a lot of code so I'm trying to put whats important